# CSS/HTML white space

Tags: html, css

The page isn't long enough (I'm on a 24" screen), so there is a white space at the bottom. Is there anyway to set some sort of min-height on the page? Or any solution? Never had to deal with this before.

Comment: offtopic: the part that slides down on a mouseover is kinda counter-intuitive and (not meaning to be harsh) irritating. I suggest you choose some alternative..

Comment: was actually a bug, wasn't supposed to slide on the info page. appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is actually your `background-image` (200px x 200px white image) over-riding your `background-color` (#000000) choice.

Try moving your `background-image` into a different part of the page, like putting wrapping div around your `.container_12` with a 100% width.

Comment: You might also want to watch your `float` settings.  `#container` is not floated, but is inside of a `.container_12` which is floated.  960.gs has plenty of options for getting around this (like the `alpha` and `omega` classes).

Answer (score 3):

You can set the body to a background color.  What did you want to have at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).